# Can't install Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion w5040la

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I've got a HP Pavilion w5040la, a tower model, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 but when I'm booting it with the cd in it, a green screen appears and I don't know why.

If i remove the cd, Windows XP runs normal :/

Answer (score 0):

You should check the hardware support matrix on the Ubuntu site. This provides hardware support and  release information. It may be that 14.04 is not supported on the Pavilion w5040la.

Next, make sure that you have the CD selected before the hard drive as a bootable device in the PC's BIOS. Hit F8 or F10, depending on model, to get to the BIOS, then select Boot Order to set the CD before the hard drive.

Then check the CD. Did you create it using the tools recommended on the Ubuntu site, as there are special instructions to make sure you have a bootable CD.